# Strongly typed view in partial view not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having an issue with my form submission in strongly typed view. My view is partial and embedded in another strongly typed view that has no form in it. My parent view controller returns type JobsListViewModel.

```
public class JobsListViewModel
{
        public IEnumerable<JobPost> JobPosts { get; set; }
        public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
        public SearchTerms searchTerms { get; set; }
 }
```

Note: JobPosts is a model class itself and i use it on my parent view. searchterms is a model class which i use in my partial view. 
The form in my partial view is like below.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("List", "Search",  
          FormMethod.Post, new { @class="form-group text-right" }))
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.searchTerms.searchText,new {@class="form-control"})
  @Html.DropDownListFor(func=>func.searchTerms.JobFunction,ViewBag.JobFunction as SelectList,"Job Function",new {@class="dropdown"})
   ....                               

}
```

My Post controller method is like below.

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult List(SearchTerms search,int page = 1)
{
 ....
}
```

On my form submit , it calls my Post controller method. However, SearchTerms is always empty. It totally does not bind. Please is there any where i can acheive this ? does it have to do with my view being a partial view ? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You partial is generating controls based on typeof `JobsListViewModel`. For example you textbox will look like

```
<input type="text" name="searchTerms.searchText" ... />
```

but your posting back only to typeof `SearchTerms`. Typeof `SearchTerms` does not contain a property `searchTerms` so binding fails.

You can use the `Prefix` property of the `[Bind]` attribute to effectively ignore the prefix

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult List([Bind(Prefix="searchTerm")]SearchTerms search, int page = 1)
```

Alternatively you can post back the model the view was based on

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult List(JobsListViewModel model, int page = 1)
```

Comment: thank you. The first one (i.e the one with prefix) `[Bind(Prefix="searchTerm")]SearchTerms search` returns null. However the second one works fine. I am kind of scared of passing the JobsListViewModel  for the JobPost may be in thousands and therefore large. Wouldn't there be a performance issue if pass i pass the JobsListViewModel  ? just curious . Thank you .

Comment: Sorry i speeled the SearchTerms wrong that was why the prefix was not working before. It's fine now. Thanks for ur time

Comment: If the first one is not working it could be because your `SearchTerms` model contains a property named `search`. You need to post your models to be sure. In any case your form does not contain any properties for `JobPosts` (at least you have not shown any) so no `JobPosts` will post back and the property will be an empty list